# How to find Sha1 fingerprint certification in flutter project in android studio #firebase #flutter #androidstudio

Tags: flutter, firebase, android-studio, sha, certificate-signing-request

how to find SHA 1 key in androidstudio for flutter

Easy method to find Sha 1 key...not so may steps

Answer (score 2):

**SHA-1 & SHA-256 Key for Mac & Windows :-**

1. Mac :- keytool -list -v -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore -alias androiddebugkey -storepass android -keypass android
2. Windows :- keytool -list -v -keystore "%USERPROFILE%.android\debug.keystore" -alias androiddebugkey -storepass android -keypass android

Answer (score 2):

Well, there one more alternative to find the Sha and Sha1 key in Vs code. You just have to go in to the terminal and move to the Android directory of your project then type this command

./ gradleW signingReport

Comment: first open the Terminal option( u will find it besides of Debug console ). type 1. cd android. 2. ./ gradleW signingReport